# Getting stack overflow when overloaded >> operator function is called for a class. What changes do i need to make?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Below is the class file for which >> operator is overloaded.

```
class Timepoint {
public:
    Timepoint();
    Timepoint(unsigned short yearValue = 9999, unsigned short month = 12, unsigned short date = 31, unsigned short hour = 23, unsigned short minute = 59);
    ~Timepoint();
    unsigned short get_dayOfYear();
    void operator++();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Timepoint& timepoint);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const Timepoint&);

private:
    unsigned short dayOfYear;
    unsigned short year;
    unsigned short time;
    const static short days[];
};
```

Below is the overloaded function which is triggering the stack overflow error. I have to take time as a time stamp from user and store in objects data. when control comes to this function, stack overflow is triggered.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const Timepoint& timepoint)
{
    int day, month, hour, minute;
    std::string timestamp;
    in >> timestamp;
    std::stringstream ss(timestamp);
    ss >> timepoint.year;
    ss.ignore();
    ss >> month;
    ss.ignore();
    ss >> day;
    ss.ignore();
    ss >> hour;
    ss.ignore();
    ss >> minute;

    const_cast<Timepoint&>(timepoint).dayOfYear = timepoint.days[month] + day;
    const_cast<Timepoint&>(timepoint).time = hour * 60 + minute;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Off topic but... pass the `Timepoint` as a *non-const* reference and get rid of the `const_cast's`.

Comment: Off topic, but needing/using `const_cast` is always a code smell.

Comment: What happens when you step through this with your debugger?

Comment: Ambiguous constructor https://ideone.com/oLyZGm

Comment: `const Timepoint tp(0); std::cin >> tp;`: compiles but is undefined. I don't think you want to allow that.

Comment: Completely unrelated: a default time of 23:59 on December 31st is pretty unexpected. Most go for 00:00 on January 1st.

Answer (score 2):

`ss >> timepoint.year` is interpreted as

```
ss >> Timepoint(timepoint.year);
```

That's the only viable way to read into a `const unsigned short`. This of course results in an infinite recursion.

The root cause here is that you are, inexplicably, passing a `const` object to a function whose explicit goal is to modify that object. Just drop `const`.

You may also want to make the constructor `explicit`, to avoid such unexpected conversions.

Comment: `ss >> Timepoint(timepoint.year);` So a new object is getting constructed here?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yes, a new temporary object of type `Timepoint` is constructed, and passed to `operator>>`, which ends up being called recursively.

Comment: Thank You Igor. It worked after I made those changes.